# There is an error in this code and I can not fix it

Tags: java

There is an error somewhere inside of this code and I do not know how to fix it. When in eclipse it says that the variable is not initialized then I initialize the object with null. When I do this it says only c.courseCode can be initialized with null. Please help me!

```
class Course {
 String courseCode;
 String courseName;
 int duration;
}

public class CourseTest {
 public static void main(){
  Course c;
  c.courseCode = "C0001";
  c.courseName = "Programming in Java";
  c.duration = 4;
  System.out.println("Course Code + " + c.courseCode);
  System.out.println("Course Name + " + c.courseName);
  System.out.println("Course Duration in Months: " + c.duration);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 Course c = new Course();
```

> When you create an object, you are creating an "instance" of a class,
>   therefore "instantiating" a class. The new operator requires a single,
>   postfix argument: a call to a constructor. The name of the constructor
>   provides the name of the class to instantiate.

[reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CourseTest {
 public static void main(){
  Course c = new Course();   <----- object is not instantiated in your code
  c.courseCode = "C0001";
  c.courseName = "Programming in Java";
  c.duration = 4;
  System.out.println("Course Code + " + c.courseCode);
  System.out.println("Course Name + " + c.courseName);
  System.out.println("Course Duration in Months: " + c.duration);
 }
}
```

The code doesn't instantiate the object that has to be created for holding the values.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create the `Course` object with `new` in order to use it
2. The `main` method should receive `String[] args` in input

Therefore, these are the 2 lines you need to change:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
Course c = new Course();
```